# Need 1200 users to be able to just create cases, What licence or approach need to use?

Tags: licenses, service

I need to migrate a legacy system that its used to log Claims (cases) and have 1200 users because theres no need for a licence in that web app.

I want to migrate this web app to salesforce but I have the problem that theres no way to pay 1200 Licenses just to create a case occasionally and follow up all the cases that they create.

Any ideas to approach this?

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look into Communities.
They offer exactly what you need: people without the usual Salesforce credentials, but some limited capabilities in system.
There's even a way to pay per-login, not per user. (So one user who logs in once a month to submit a case is cheaper than their friend who logs in every day).